# HTML5 Banner Disappears After Playing

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, banner, banner-ads

I created [this HTML5 banner](http://bluefruit.com/clients/greatpark/meet_the_builders/build1/300x250/300x250.html) in Adobe Animate, using the method spelled out by Cory Hudson that uses AdHelper and CreateJS.

I have not been able to reproduce the bug, but apparently, sometimes after it plays, it goes blank. The only things than remain are the outline and a lowercase “t,” sometimes along with a broken image icon. It plays normally first and can take minutes before it goes blank. This is happening on Mac OS 10.11.6/Safari 10.0 and Windows 7/“the latest Chrome.”

Based on posts about seemingly similar issues, I tried a couple things. I switched from the use of sprites to individual image files. That didn't help. [In this version](http://bluefruit.com/clients/greatpark/meet_the_builders/build3/300x250/300x250.html), I tried commenting-out this line of code: `.setSleep(15,0,0)`. I'm not sure if this did the trick though.

Can anyone reproduce the bug? If so, is my fix working? Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I just this on my MAC, I tried it in both Firefox (49.0.1) and Safari (10.0, 12602.1.50.0.10), running on OSX Sierra version 10.12, the animation played fine and at the end the image remained.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solved my issue yet, because I can't reproduce the bug, but someone pointed me to [Cory Hudson's latest templates](http://blogs.adobe.com/animate/creating-html5-ads-with-animate-cc-google-html5-ad-templates/). I've used those and everything seems to be working fine.